# How can I use Tier Pricing with Configurable Products? (Magento 1.4+)

Tags: zend-framework, magento

**How can I use/setup Tier Pricing with Configurable Products? (Magento 1.4+)**

There was an extension to do this but I think it is only for Magento 1.3.

Tried to setup tiers in my Simple Products, but those do not show up, or do not activate when I add to cart from my Config Product page.

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks.

Edit:

**In my case, I would like to use the Tier Pricing FROM the Simple Product. and not use the Tier Pricing from the Config. Product**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configurable products do not use any of the information from simple products apart from the attribute values on which the configurable product is pivoted. That means that Descriptions, Prices, Images and other data can be changed in the simple products, and the configurable products will not be changed whatsoever.

Unfortunately, hacking the price of a product in the Magento cart is difficult, as it is refreshed from the record every time the page is loaded, so what you're trying to accomplish isn't going to happen any time soon.

---

Your best bet might be to write a short script that will grab the simple product prices and update the configurable product record periodically. This would not need to hack through the Magento logic to work.

Hope that helps. Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2):

For anyone reading this, use this free extension:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Matt+Dean/extension/596/simple-configurable-products#overview

It will take the pricing from the simple product the only downside is you manually have to come up with a way to show the tiers on the configurable product page.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I just came across this myself. I am on Magento CE 1.6 and the extension recommended here was only up to 1.5.

I found that Grouped products do exactly that - they pull pricing (as well as tiered pricing) from the simple product. They are very easy to set up and work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but following up to say that the Simple Configurable Products extension works great at updating the price in a simple manner.

Having one problem however. I only have a product image assigned to my configurable product, not the simple ones linked to it. When I add a product to my cart with this extension it adds the simple product, which means there is no product image. Is there a way to display the parent photo in cart? Totally find editing code if that will get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple workaround for this, i have a configurable product with 3 options, e put this three options visible only for catalog and then assign this simple products to a categorie named tier prices, so, customer who want quantity discount just have to browse that category and found there all the available products.

Hope this help!!

Regards,